# SQL JOIN Statement

Tags: sql

```
Select name_A,name_B 
 From 
 A inner join B on A.Id_a = B.Id_a
```

this returns the values based  on the `A.Id_a = B.Id_a` but I have also records in table A which are not related to table B which i want to read out as the same time. In this case I want to read all `name_A` and `name_B` based on `A.Id_a = B_a.Id`. Any Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a left join:

```
Select name_A,name_B 
 From 
 A left  join B on A.Id_a = B.Id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name_A,name_B 
 From 
 A left join B on A.Id_a = B.Id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a visual person so I find
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html
very handy from time to time.

Both answers above are correct an OUTER join LEFT or right depending on which table is listed first is required.